# what's cURL 302 found?

Tags: curl

cURL give me this page :

> 302 Found
>
> The document has been temporarily moved to here.

for some websites, but in browser that site load perfect.
how can i fix it?

Comment: Probably a way to redirect web pages.

Comment: "The HTTP response status code 302 Found is the most common way of performing a redirection." - quoted from [Wikipedia's HTTP 302 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

Answer (score 30):

You need to add the -L option see manpage quote:

> -L, --location
>
> (HTTP/HTTPS) If the server reports that the requested page has moved
>   to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX
>   response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new
>   place. If used together with -i, --include or -I, --head, headers from
>   all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl
>   only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes
>   curl to a different host, it won't be able to intercept the
>   user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You
>   can limit the amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs
>   option.
>
> When curl follows a redirect and the request is not a plain GET (for
>   example POST or PUT), it will do the following request with a GET if
>   the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any
>   other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following request using the same
>   unmodified method.

Reference: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html